# Showing thin sets are Lebesgue measurable

Tags: lebesgue-measure, several-complex-variables

I'm reading through *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables* and have come across a proof I can't get through concerning thin sets. I'll include the definition of a thin set since it's not too common a notion:

> Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be open and $E\subseteq D$. $E$ is said to be **thin** if for every $p\in D$, there is $r>0$ such that there is a non-constant holomorphic function $f$ on $B(p,r)$ satisfying $f|_{E\cap B(p,r)} \equiv 0$.

Effectively, thin sets are sets that locally are zero sets of holomorphic functions. It is easy to see that if thin sets are Lebesgue measurable, they have to have measure zero however I have no idea how to show they are Lebesgue measurable. Marrying the complex analysis definition with measurability conditions is escaping me. Can anyone provide a hint? (Not a full proof, I'd like to figure that out on my own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Effectively, thin sets are sets that locally are zero sets of holomorphic functions.

They are (locally) contained in zero sets of non-constant holomorphic functions, not necessarily the full zero set.

To prove the Lebesgue-measurability of thin sets, show that the zero set of a non-constant holomorphic function is a null-set, and that you need only countably many to cover the thin set.

Comment: Quite right about the correction. I should have been a little more careful with my statement. I was considering showing that the zero set of a holomorphic function is a null set but I couldn't see how to go from there to a thin set. This is a great hint! I'll update when I've figured it out. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: I think I got it. First as you suggested we need to show that the zero set of any non-constant holomorphic function has measure zero. Since holomorphic functions are continuous and continuous functions are measurable, we have that the inverse image of $\{0\}$ (which is measurable) under any holomorphic function is a measurable set. The zero set must also have measure zero since otherwise-by the inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure-it would contain an open set and would force the function to be zero (by the Identity Theorem). ...

Comment: D'oh. My idea was wrong for the last part. I'm close though! I'll add more details when I figure out the rest.

Comment: There are of course many ways to show it. A relatively easy one uses induction and the identity theorem.